# How to make dex2jar to skip certain classes while converting dex to jar?

Tags: java, android, jar, dex, dex2jar

I'm making an application that uses the **dex2jar** library to convert a dex file (from an android application package) to a jar file. But the process takes quite long especially due to android.support.*x* classes. Is there a way to make dex2jar skip certain classes (that we specify) while decompiling ?

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
DexFileReader reader = new DexFileReader(new File(PackageDir));
Dex2jar.from(reader)
.reUseReg(reuseReg)
.topoLogicalSort(topologicalSort || topologicalSort1)
.skipDebug(!debugInfo)
.optimizeSynchronized(optmizeSynchronized)
.printIR(printIR)
.verbose(verbose)
.to(file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [dexlib2](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22dexlib2%22) to load the dex file, remove the classes you're not interested in, and then build a new dex file

```
int api = 19;
DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(dexFilePath, api);

List<ClassDef> classes = new ArrayList<ClassDef>();

for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
    if (!classDef.getType().startsWith("Landroid/support/")) {
        classes.add(classDef);
    }
}

dexFile = new ImmutableDexFile(classes);
DexFileFactory.writeDexFile(dexFilePath, dexFile);
```

Comment: @JesusFreke... I'll give it a try.. But one small doubt.. Why are we specifying  the API level ?

Comment: Is there any way i can read the classes.dex directly from an apk file ?

Comment: @niranjan94 Api level is to determine which set of opcodes to use. DexFileFactory.loadDexFile accepts either a dex file or an apk.